# Server Hangs on booting grub, Just displays "GRUB C"

Tags: grub

I have install oracle linux 4.5 on server twice but having same problem.
The server hangs on booting just displays "**GRUB C**" i don't know why is it happening.

Please advice is it the drive issue.

Answer (score 1):

that mean that for some reason, grub is installed on the wrong drive or file system. I have to deal with that problem a number of times. If I recall from memory:

1) Boot into rescue mode and have it mount all the partitions. Make note of the location of the location of the boot file system (or the file system that is marked bootable). Lets assume that its /boot

2) Go into chroot on the root file system.

3) Look at the /boot/grub/device.map - it should map to the correct drive and file systems, but because of how grub sometimes mis-read the BIOS during the install, it is probably not correct (likely you were installing from an external USB or other device that is ordinarily not connected). Please check the grub manual for details.

4) Afterwards, make sure that the "root" directive in /boot/grub/grub.conf is pointed to the correct file system. Again, please check the grub manual for details. Note that drive and file system part of the HD directive (hdX,X) starts at "0", where the drive and file system starts at "a" and "1" - don't get confused with both. :)

5) After that is corrected, run "grub-install /dev/FILESYSTEM", where FILESYSTEM is your root file system (assuming that /boot is in a separate file system).

6) do sync && sync && sync and then type in exit twice. It will reboot at that point.

7) It should work from there. If not, boot into rescue mode and try again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Debian and one old laptop, but only for GRUB2. When I changed grub to older version the problem disappeared.

Comment: The Problem got resolved when i removed one hard drive from the system. Initially i got 2.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Problem was there were 2 hard drives on the system and when i remove one it got resolved.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.